# Re-frame, reagent component life cycle and figwheel

Tags: reagent, figwheel, re-frame

I'm trying to learn a lot of things at the same time, so my question could be a little off target.

I have created a re-frame-template project with lein and I have my default main component:

```
(defn main-panel []
  (let [name (subscribe [:name])]
    (fn [] [:div [:h1 @name]])))
```

I wanted to add an event listener for keypress, but I couldn't manage to do it correctly: if I only set (using domina) the `(listen! ...)` in the `:component-did-mount`, on every figwheel reload a new even listener is added to the old one(s). If I set the `unlisten!` in `component-will-unmount`, I get no result on keypress.

What I noticed is that on every figwheel reload, the `:component-will-unmount` is triggered immediatly after the `:component-did-mount`!

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found my mistake.
I had to call the react "methods" with `with-meta`.

So, for example:

```
(with-meta myComponent {:component-did-mount #(ev/listen! ...)
                        :component-will-unmount #(ev/unlisten! ...)})
```

Comment: Don't use with-meta.  Very clumsy.
https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#form-3-a-class-with-life-cycle-methods

Comment: Umm thanks for the link! Why do you think it's clumsy? That form-3 look awfully verbose!